# Is there a font/format I can use to keep the size of each character equal when posting riddles?

Tags: support, formatting, riddles

When I write rhyming riddles, I make it a challenge for me to use the exact same amount of characters in each line.

When that happens, congrats to me!

But the rendered output doesn't show my effort.

Is there a font/format I can use to keep the size of each character equal when posting riddles?

---

#### Example:

[image: Riddle]

Comment: If it's a challenge _for you_ then why do you care how it looks _for others_? I'm pretty sure no one else will enjoy reading or solving your puzzles more as a result of being able to see that different lines are the same length. I suggest enjoying the nice alignment while editing the question, and then leaving it formatted normally so that solvers can read it as easily as possible.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan The concept of alignment loosely relates to rhyming, making the riddle more enjoyable. Anyone can argue that it doesn't, but I still think so.

Comment: My guess is that for _most_ readers the riddle will not be made more enjoyable by having it presented in a monospaced font (which is harder to read) that makes the lines visibly the same length. I could, of course, be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more idea is to use mathjax here. But note that it makes the loading a few milliseconds slower and it is not supported in very old systems.
You're Lucky, I have been interested in $\mathtt{MathJax}$\ $\LaTeX$ recently, and I have been collecting symbols, methods and $\boldsymbol{Fonts}$.

**1.** Blackboard bold:

- This font only uses uppercase letters;

$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
Code: `$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$`

**2.** Calligraphic letters:

- This font uses only uppercase letters;

$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
Code: `$\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$`

**3.** Fraktur letters:

- This font uses both uppercase and lowercase letters;

$\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
Code: `$\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$`

**4.** Roman letters:

- This font uses both uppercase and lowercase letters;

$\mathrm{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
Code: `$\mathrm{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$`

**5.** Bold Face:

- This font uses both uppercase and lowercase letters;

$\mathbf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
Code: `$\mathbf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$`

**6.** Bold Italics:

- This font uses both uppercase and lowercase letters;

$\boldsymbol{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
Code: `$\boldsymbol{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$`

**7.** Italics:

- This font uses both uppercase and lowercase letters;

$\mathit{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
Code: `$\mathit{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$`

**8.** Typewriter:

- This font uses both uppercase and lowercase letters;

$\mathtt{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
Code: `$\mathtt{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$`

**9.** Sans-Serif Font:

- This font uses both uppercase and lowercase letters;

$\mathsf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
Code: `$\mathsf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$`

**10.** Script letters:

- This font uses both uppercase and lowercase letters;

$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
Code: `$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$`

**11.** Normal Raw Text:

- This font uses both uppercase and lowercase letters
- This is not a real font - It is just raw text

$\text{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
Code: `$\text{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$`

Ok if you read this fully, maybe you think; What is the difference between `\text{}` and `\mathrm{}`?They both look same.
Well, the difference is, that `\text{}` is raw. Let's test it out:
The [Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) symbols in $\LaTeX$ is just `$\pi$`.
It looks like this in normal $\LaTeX$: $\pi$
In Roman Letters: $\mathrm{\pi}$(Code: `$\mathrm{\pi}$`)
But because the `$\text{}$` method is raw, it shows this: $\text{\pi}$(Code: `$\text{\pi}$`)

Answer (score 3):

The only option on Stack Exchange is to use 'code formatting', also know as [preformatted text](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code). [Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/100424/11110) is a recent example. The easiest way to achieve this is to select the riddle, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or the <kbd>{ }</kbd> button in the toolbar above the edit area. (You probably know this because you're active on Stack Overflow; other users might not.)

```
If my prefix had an id, its photo would have only one eye.

If my suffix had a body, its body would have only one eye.

My infix: You are a letter.

Me: My shape is for better.
```

Do note that this makes the riddle slightly harder to read, and people are not used to it and [remove it](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/100452/revisions) since blockquotes are the standard way to display riddles. An exception will be made if it's vital to the puzzle, but this doesn't seem to be the case here.

Another   option   would   be to use one or more [alternative space characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515417/4751173) to equalize the displayed lengths. It [doesn't seem to negatively influence searching](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22another+option+would+be%22), which was my main concern. It might be that depending on a user's browser, OS or zoom settings, the aligning might not work; this is not a problem if you use preformatted text.

In both cases, it's best to indicate that the non-standard formatting is intentional.

Comment: Code formatting used for non-code things is usually removed, all over the network. (In fact I did that with this user's puzzle before seeing this meta post, replacing it by a normal quote block.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your riddle to be displayed in a very distinctive way - for whatever reason - you can always upload it as an image.

Just be aware, that some people will prefer text - maybe even because they are handicapped and need the computer to "read" it to them.
So, if it is purely for esthetics, I possibly wouldn´t do it. And I would provide the plain text nevertheless.

Comment: I've thought of that before, but some users might want to copy-paste text, and images won't allow them to.

Comment: I guess you´ve commented before I edited my own post :c)  
That´s why I suggested to add the plain-text as well. 
I think an example for "picture" being used without a real need for it  are the ...word TM type puzzles like [this example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49065/what-is-a-united-word/49067#49067). It was commonly accepted, because it made a specific type of puzzle very recognizable. But plain text was added for ease of use. I could imagine a similar visual "branding" for your own puzzles, if this is what pleases you personally.